# Подключение редактора Django-Pagedown к своему проекту

Tags: html, css, django, form, markdown

Изучаю фреймворк **Django**. На курсах выбрал себе тему проекта в стиле "блог", связанный с медициной.
Периодически пользуясь *stackoverflow* приглянулся редактор, в котором, собственно, и пишу вопрос.

Гугл подсказал, что *stackoverflow* использует вот этот [редактор](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown#customizing-the-widget).

Установил по инструкции, все работает, но вид у меня абсолютно непрактичный и не вызывает желание пользоваться таким редактором.

Прикладываю код html шаблона создания поста.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %}
    Создать публикацию - {{block.super}}
{% endblock %}
{% block mark_style %}
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock mark_style %}
```

```
{% block content %}

<form  class="" action="{% url 'blog:post_create_url' %}" method="post">
    
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {% if field.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ field.errors }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.label }}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-dark"> Опубликовать</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Дополнительно, вот скрин получевшегося.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используются теги типа {{ }}, к которым я не могу традиционно применить теги стиля `<style></style>`.

Конечная цель привести общий вид поля `Body` к виду поля `Основная часть` встроенного редактора stackoverflow.

Т.к. на курсах фронтенд направлению отводилось совсем немного, прошу помочь, пояснить и направить на решение этой задачи.

Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение сам, поэтому отвечаю на собственный вопрос.

Решение простое.
В режиме "Исследовать элемент" выбираем нужный класс в теге(`<div>, <ul>, <li>`, зависит от нужного для редактирования и стилистики) и добавляем ему стиль внутри тега `<style> </style>` в шаблоне, где используется ваш редактор.

Пример для шаблона создания публикации `post_create.html`:

```
<style>
  .wmd-button-row {
  добавляем стили: css;
  }
</style>
```

Решение простое, оно опробовано на моем небольшом проекте, оно работает.
Буду рад, если это простое решение кому-нибудь поможет.